Print numbers in PGFplots
Consider my MWE, where I want to print different numbers in frac format:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect, frac,frac whole=false, frac shift={2}}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.5}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.133333333333325e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.12}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.666666666666646e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{-1.333333333333334e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{7.200000000000000e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{6.666666666666667e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{1.333333333333333e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{-1.333333333333333e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{3.3333333}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{1.2345}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.356654}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{5}

\end{document}

whose output is the following:

works perfectly when I have a decimal number. Based on documentation:
https://tikz.dev/math-numberprinting
however, when the number is integer, appears a denominator 1. (2/1 instead 2 only, for example).
When I set the options to:
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect, frac}

the output is almost I want, but the fractions are strange.

How can I fix this, please?

with \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect, frac,frac shift={2}} ?

Not. The fractions contains the integer part

With \pgfmathifisint
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
% \usepackage{pgfplots}
% \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect, frac,frac whole=false, frac shift={2}}
\newcommand\test[1]{%
    \pgfmathifisint{#1}
        {\pgfretval}
        {\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}
    \hspace{1em} 
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {
    2,
    0.5,
    2.133333333333325e-01,
    0.12,
    2.666666666666646e-02,
    -1.333333333333334e-02,
    7.200000000000000e-01,
    6.666666666666667e-02,
    1.333333333333333e-01,
    -1.333333333333333e-02,
    3.3333333,
    1.2345,
    2.356654,
    5}
    {\test{\x}}
\end{document}



Perfect! Thank you so much.
